# /wp-admin not accessible after migrating to local host (no plugin issue)

Tags: database, migration, https

I migrated my local Wordpress site to my WPEngine account and it's been working without any problem!

After adding some content, I decided to export the database from the live version and import it to my local version so that they are synced. I adjusted the two `siteurl` and `home` fields in the database and the home page (https://localhost:8888) comes up well but the /wp-admin page is forced to https and responds with `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error.

All the other pages of the website cannot be loaded and return this error:
Not Found
The requested URL /news was not found on this server.

It seems like a "permalinks" reset problem for inner pages!

All these problems would go away if I switch the database back to the one I was using for local version so I'm pretty sure it's a database issue!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but I would try 2 things

- Change `siteurl` and `homeurl` into http:// and not https://, for https:// to work locally you'll need a local SSL certificate. You can easily manage this with MAMP PRO. But it's not required for your local site to work at all.
- Could you check if .htaccess is missing from your projects root folder. This is the directory where wp-config.php is located. This has impact on the permalinks, most-likely if the homepage is working and nothing else is, the .htaccess is missing.

Hope this helps out

Comment: Thanks Mathias. That was helpful! The `siteurl` and `homeurl` fields are correct (http). I edited the `.htaccess` file to the default of Wordpress and it fixed the permalinks! but I still get my `/wp-admin` page redirected to https... Is there any tricks other than local ssl cert. to solve that?

Comment: Can you check if FORCE_SSL_ADMIN or FORCE_SSL_LOGIN is defined in wp-config.php AND set to true, otherwise wp-admin should use the same protocol as defined in siteurl. If that doesn't work out, maybe try troubleshooting by disabling plugins one by one.